# MySQL get rows from array

Tags: php, mysql, performance, left-join

I got a users table in my project

```
id   |    name    |    user_group
-----+------------+----------------
1    |   name     |     1
2    |   name     |     1
3    |   name     |     2
4    |   name     |     2
5    |   name     |     2
6    |   name     |     2
7    |   name     |     2
------------------------------------
```

Each user is associated with a group

Also users can upload images to the site so I got a table for images.

```
id    |     image_name      | user_id       |   uploaded_date
------+---------------------+---------------+--------------------------
1     |    dder.jpg         |    1          |    2014-12-12 00:00:00
2     |    dder.jpg         |    1          |    2014-12-12 00:00:00
3     |    dder.jpg         |    2          |    2014-12-12 00:00:00
4     |    dder.jpg         |    3          |    2014-12-12 00:00:00
5     |    dder.jpg         |    6          |    2014-12-12 00:00:00
6     |    dder.jpg         |    7          |    2014-12-12 00:00:00
7     |    dder.jpg         |    7          |    2014-12-12 00:00:00
8     |    dder.jpg         |    5          |    2014-12-12 00:00:00
9     |    dder.jpg         |    2          |    2014-12-12 00:00:00
10    |    dder.jpg         |    1          |    2014-12-12 00:00:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now my question is I needs to get the list of images uploaded by **user_group=2** in the DESC of **uploaded_date**

Can anyone please help me with a simple query ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
    SELECT i.* 
      FROM images i
INNER JOIN users u 
           ON i.user_id = u.id
     WHERE u.user_group = 2
  ORDER BY i.uploaded_date DESC
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31511c/1). For performance, it's important to have a foreign key set on `user_id` column in `images` table, that references `id` column in `users` table.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this like so: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28a18/1

```
SELECT     img.image_name
FROM       images img
INNER JOIN users usr
ON         img.user_id = usr.id
WHERE      usr.user_group = 2
ORDER BY   img.uploaded_date DESC
```

However, if you want to have more than one user_group assigned to a user at some point, you should have something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f938/1